# Class Probability Tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to create a multi-band raster using the class probability tool in ArGIS Desktop 10.2. I used the classified image I created based on my signature file as the input raster, and my training classes (.gsg) extention as my input signature file. All I get as an output when the tool runs is a mostly grey layer with no actual information attached to it. Anyone have any ideas about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more precise details of what you did, please?